# Yaesu FT-270 doesn't remember tone ctcss

Tags: yaesu

I have a repeater frequency saved.  When I set a tone, it works, but when I turn the device off and on again, the tone setting part is "gone".  Manual CTCSS operation #7 "When you have made your selection, press the F/L key to save..."

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I have to "re save" that frequency (even though it says it's on "remembered frequency 4") as frequency 4 *again* after setting tone, then it'll preserve the tone setting.

Comment: Probably the first save saves the tone in the VFO, and the second save saves the vfo settings to the channel memory.